# Calculate running clossing stock and profit by average purchase price in mysql

Tags: mysql

I need to insert new quantities to the stock table (a1) from source table (a2) and when on insertion closing stock, profit should be calculated. My stock (a1) table as

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `a1` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `trs_date` date NOT NULL,
  `product_id` int NOT NULL,
  `qty_in` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL,
  `price_in` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL,
  `amount_in` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL,
  `qty_out` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL,
  `price_out` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL,
  `amount_out` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL,
  `qty_bal` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL,
  `price_bal` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL,
  `amount_bal` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL,
  `profit` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;


INSERT INTO `a1` (`id`, `trs_date`, `product_id`, `qty_in`, `price_in`, `amount_in`, `qty_out`, `price_out`, `amount_out`, `qty_bal`, `price_bal`, `amount_bal`, `profit`) VALUES
(1, '2022-01-01', 1, '10.00', '2.00', '20.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '10.00', '2.00', '20.00', '0.00'),
(2, '2022-01-01', 2, '20.00', '10.00', '200.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '20.00', '10.00', '200.00', '0.00'),
(3, '2022-01-02', 1, '5.00', '3.00', '15.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '15.00', '2.33', '35.00', '0.00'),
(4, '2022-01-02', 2, '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '5.00', '8.00', '40.00', '15.00', '10.00', '150.00', '-10.00'),
(5, '2022-01-03', 1, '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '8.00', '9.00', '72.00', '7.00', '2.33', '16.31', '53.36');
```

and Source Table (a2) as

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `a2` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `trs_date` date NOT NULL,
  `product_id` int NOT NULL,
  `qty_in` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL,
  `price_in` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL,
  `amount_in` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL,
  `qty_out` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL,
  `price_out` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL,
  `amount_out` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

INSERT INTO `a2` (`id`, `trs_date`, `product_id`, `qty_in`, `price_in`, `amount_in`, `qty_out`, `price_out`, `amount_out`) VALUES
(4, '2022-01-03', 1, '50.00', '4.00', '200.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00'),
(5, '2022-01-04', 2, '60.00', '8.00', '480.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00'),
(6, '2022-01-05', 1, '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '10.00', '15.00', '150.00');
```

Now I need to insert data from a2 to a1 and closing quantity,rate,amount and profit should be calculated.

> Closing Quantity = Previous Quantity + Quantity In - Quantity Out
>
> Closing Price *(Average Purchase Price)*= (Previous Amount Balance + Amount In) / (Previous
> Quantity + Quantity In)
>
> Closing Amount = Closing Quantity * Closing Price
>
> Profit = Quantity Out * (Price Out - Closing Price)

My query as follows

```
insert into a1 (trs_date, product_id, qty_in,price_in,amount_in,qty_out,price_out,amount_out,
                qty_bal,price_bal,amount_bal,profit)
with cte_balance as (
    select 
        *,
        row_number() over (partition by product_id order by trs_date desc, id desc) as rn
    from a1
),
cte_receive as (
    select 
        id, trs_date, product_id, qty_in,price_in,amount_in,qty_out,price_out,amount_out,
        qty_bal,price_bal,amount_bal,profit, rn as skip_flag 
    from cte_balance where rn = 1
        union all
    select 
        id, trs_date, product_id, qty_in,price_in,amount_in,qty_out,price_out,amount_out,
        0 AS qty_bal,0 AS price_bal,0 AS amount_bal,0 AS profit,0 as skip_flag 
    from a2
),
cte_new_balance as (
    select 
        id, trs_date, product_id, qty_in,price_in,amount_in,qty_out,price_out,amount_out,
        (LAG(qty_bal) over (partition by product_id order by skip_flag DESC, trs_date, id)+qty_in-qty_out) as qty_bal,
        0 as amt_bal,
        (LAG (amount_bal) over (partition by product_id order by skip_flag DESC, trs_date, id)+ amount_bal)/
        (LAG (qty_bal) over (partition by product_id order by skip_flag DESC, trs_date, id)+ qty_bal) as rate_bal,
        0 AS new_profit,
        skip_flag
    from cte_receive
)

select 
    trs_date, product_id, qty_in,price_in,amount_in,qty_out,price_out,amount_out,
    qty_bal as qty_bal,rate_bal AS price_bal,qty_bal*rate_bal AS amount_bal,new_profit AS profit
from cte_new_balance
where skip_flag = 0;
```

Where `cte_balance` is to take latest data of each product from table a1, and `cte_receive` combines the latest data with new data from a2. The query giving unexpected result, my expected result, Table a1 should be as
[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Get last `qty_bal` per product (Note to `order by trs_date desc, id desc` in case more than one row in a day)
2. Union with receives in `a2` (added `skip_flag`)
3. Calculate new `qty_bal` per row (To `order by trs_date, id` to get data in proper order)

```sql
insert into a1 (trs_date, product_id, qty_in, qty_out, qty_bal)
with cte_balance as (
select id, trs_date, product_id, qty_in, qty_out, qty_bal,
       row_number() over (partition by product_id order by trs_date desc, id desc) as rn
  from a1),
cte_receive as (
select id, trs_date, product_id, 0 as qty_in, 0 as qty_out, qty_bal, rn as skip_flag from cte_balance where rn = 1
 union all
select id, trs_date, product_id, qty_in, qty_out, qty_in-qty_out, 0 from a2),
cte_new_balance as (
select id, trs_date, product_id, qty_in, qty_out, qty_bal,
       sum(qty_bal) over (partition by product_id order by trs_date, id) as new_bal,
       skip_flag
  from cte_receive)
select trs_date, product_id, qty_in, qty_out, new_bal as qty_bal
  from cte_new_balance
 where skip_flag = 0;
```